# Changing coordinate system and extent of shapefile in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, r, extents

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.2.

I tried to change the coordinate system in a shapefile from TM65 / Irish National Grid to the coordinate system of a raster file (wgs_1984) opened in the same session. I want to use the shapefile to cookiecut the raster file (that I create from a NetCDF file).

First let's look at the shapefile that I want to be my cutter:
When I open the first shapefile (Ireland) and look at properties->source, I see:

```
Data Type:  Shapefile Feature Class 
Shapefile:  C:\Shapefiles\IReland.shp
Geometry Type:  Polygon
Coordinates have Z values:  No 
Coordinates have measures:  No 

Projected Coordinate System:    TM65 / Irish National Grid
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
false_easting:  200000.00000000
false_northing: 250000.00000000
central_meridian:   -8.00000000
scale_factor:   1.00003500
latitude_of_origin: 53.50000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_TM65
Datum:  D_TM65
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

I have a NetCDF file that I am opening in R. This code will create a reproducible example file NetCDF in R:

```
#create data
vap=array(1:100, c(351,451,365))

#create the list
Variable <- list(Data = vap)
xyCoords <- list(x = seq(from = -10.763300, to = -5.238170, by = 0.01578607), y = seq(from = 51.36150, to = 55.43160, by = 0.009044647))
Dates <- list(start = seq(as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2005-12-31"), by="days"), end=seq(as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2005-12-31"), by="days"))
#All <- list(Variable = Variable, xyCoords=xyCoords,Dates=Dates)
All <- list(Variable = Variable,Data=vap, xyCoords=xyCoords,Dates=Dates)

data<-aperm(All$Data)
#----------------
# Make dimensions
#----------------
xvals<- All$xyCoords$x
yvals<- All$xyCoords$y

nx <- length(xvals)
ny <- length(yvals)

xdim2 <- ncdim_def( 'lon', 'degrees_east',longname="longitude", xvals )
ydim2 <- ncdim_def( 'lat', 'degrees_north',longname="latitude", yvals )
tdim2 <- ncdim_def( 'time', 'months since 1949-12-01 00:00:00Z',longname="time", 0:11, unlim=TRUE )
#---------
# Make var
#---------
mv <- 1.00000002004088e+20     # missing value
var_hur <- ncvar_def( 'hur', '%', list(xdim2,ydim2,tdim2), mv )

#---------------------
# Make new output file
#---------------------
output_fname <- "test.nc"
ncid_hur <- nc_create( output_fname, list(var_hur))

#-------------------------------
# Put the data in the file
#-------------------------------
ncvar_put( ncid_hur, var_hur, data, start=c(1,1,1), count=c(nx,ny,365))

nc_close( ncid_hur)
```

Then I read in the NetCDF file into ArcGIS using 'Make NetCDF Raster Layer' and these are the 'Properties->extent':
[image]

I want to make the two files match up (in relation to their projections), so I can use the shapefile to cookiecut out data from the raster (in R).

I used the `Data Management Tools->Projections and transformations->Project` option to project my shapefile based on the projection of the raster, however,
[image]

the extent did not change in the newly projected shapefile?
[image]

Ultimately, I want to make the two files match up (in relation to their projections), so I can use the shapefile to extract data from the raster based on the shapefile (in R).
How can I make the extents match up?

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to figure out what went wrong. What were the extents before reprojection? What are the extents in the new shapefile? How many features are in each? Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: Also, if the map is TM65 and you project your shapefile to wgs84 and load that back into the map the data will be projected "on the fly" back to TM65 as that is what the map is. As @Vince says you don't provide enough information.